unrealistic Trading volume comparing to liquidity

I noticed these numbers of spl token on some decentralized exchange, as you see the total liquidity is only $520, yet the trading volume exceeds $1 million.
Is this realistic, or could there be something I'm misunderstanding about how liquidity and trading volume relate?
How can a token maintain such high volume with such low liquidity?

Trading volume is made by the buyers and sellers, while total liquidity's data is from the pooled amount from basevault and quotevault of the pair address of the token. If the pooled token in basevault is worth $260 and quotevault is worth $260, you will retrieve the value of liquidity by adding them. To retrieve the basevault and quotevault of the token, you can check it here.
https://api-v3.raydium.io/pools/key/ids?ids= (pair address)
look for the "vault, A and B"
and you can check their balances on Solscan.
